# Aero transitions not active at startup

Tags: windows-7, aero

I'm facing this weird problem.

Every time I startup my pc, aero transitions (e.g. windows fade in on open, fade out on close, reduce to taskbar etc..) are not active.

I need to go to `System Properties` then `Advanced system settings` then `Performance settings`, make some change and apply.

Is there a way to restore the standard behavior?

Note that I have all the transparencies etc..

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you: 1. [perform a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us), or 2. create/use a different user account?

Comment: By only disabling "Load startup items" in **msconfig**, the problem has gone. Now I need to find the culprit. What does exactly that check disable? I suppose HKLM/Run and HKCU/Run + Startup menu items.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You can select the **Startup** tab to check the existing items. Then you can enable just half of them and restart Windows. If you get the same issue, you split the enabled items in half again, and repeat the same process till you find the cause; if you don't, you try the other half and do the same.

Comment: Binary search tree? :D

Comment: Yeah. `log2(x)` tries at worst, where `x` is the amount of startup items. Please report back your findings when you're done :)

Comment: Actually, by remembering what I installed recently, I found it at the second guess. It seems to be the **Citrix receiver** (for remote desktop). I will investigate if it's necessary to leave it in startup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15951/discussion-between-and31415-and-teejay).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Clean boot

To troubleshoot this issue you can start by [performing a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us):

1. Log on with an administrator account.
2. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type or paste `msconfig.exe` in the text box, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. On the **General** tab, select **Selective startup**, and disable the **Load startup items** option.
4. Switch to the **Services** tab, enable the **Hide all Microsoft services** option, and click **Disable all**.
5. Click **OK**, then restart Windows to apply the changes.

### Pinpointing the issue

In a clean environment Windows will use just a minimal set of drivers and startup programs. At this point, one of the following might happen:

- **The problem is *still* there.**
   
  All the items that were temporarily disabled are unrelated, and you need to look elsewhere.
- **The problem is gone for good.**
  Whatever got disabled was involved, somehow. More tests are required to find the actual culprit.

Assuming the latter case, here's how you can proceed:

1. Start `msconfig.exe`, and select the **Startup** tab.
2. Check the list of existing items, and manually enable just half of them. Click **OK** when you're done, then restart Windows to apply the changes.
3. Next time Windows start, check if you're getting the issue. If you do, repeat step 2 till you find the cause; if you don't, try the other half and do the same.
4. If necessary, repeats steps 2-3 for the **Services** tab after making sure to hide Microsoft services.

**Geeky note** The whole procedure requires `log2(x)` tries at worst, where `x` is the amount of startup items. For example, if you have 16 startup items, you need 4 or less restarts. Taking the installation date for specific items might help further reduce the amount of work.

### Further reading

- [How to perform a clean boot in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us)

---

## Workaround

In this case the problem depends on **Citrix ICA client**, which is bundled with Citrix Receiver. This is what the startup entry would look like:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\concentr.exe" /startup
```

As long as the Connection Center process is not running the visual effects should be left untouched.

The program gets started automatically when launching a Citrix application through the browser, thus disabling the startup item is not enough. In order to prevent it from running, follow these steps:

1. Make sure any Citrix related program is closed.
2. Open an [elevated command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-7).
3. Type or paste the following command, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\concentr.exe" /v "Debugger" /t REG_SZ /d "systray.exe" /f
   ```

   If you're interested in how that works exactly, check this question: [How to block programs from running (Windows 7)](https://superuser.com/questions/721286/how-to-block-programs-from-running-windows-7).

### References

- [Fix for Citrix XenApp Published Apps Disabling Windows Visual Effects](http://aaronwalrath.wordpress.com/2010/12/05/fix-for-citrix-xenapp-published-apps-disabling-windows-visual-effects/)

Comment: I actually used the method involving permissions, rather than the one with the registry.

Comment: @Teejay I know, but changing the permissions requires more work, and if you were try to manually start the executable you would get an error. Using the registry method above the program will silently fail instead. In order to revert the changes all you need to do is to delete the registry key that gets created.

Comment: No side effects so far!