# Citrix Receiver (specifically concentr.exe) Disables Visual Effects

Tags: windows-10, citrix-receiver, visual-effects

I run Citrix Receiver (now bundled in Workspaces) on my personal Windows 10 desktop. I have found that it automatically disables Visual Effects, specifically "Animate windows when minimizing and maximizing". Further research points to "concentr.exe" as the culprit

What I have noticed in trying to fix this issue

- Performance Options already has "Adjust for best appearance" checked (with all the effects checked off as well including "Animate windows when minimizing and maximizing") but the windows are not animating
- Cycling once between "Adjust for best performance" and back to "Adjust for best appearance" fixes the issue (but the issue reappears on reboot)
- In HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects the VisualFXSetting is already set to "1". Cycling between "1" and "2" and back to "1" does NOT fix the issue (the cycling has to happen in the Performance Options dialog box for the issue to be resolved)
- Exiting out of Citrix Receiver (or Workspaces) reactivates the Minimize/Maximize Animations (until reboot)
- Changing the permissions for the concentr.exe as described in the Aaron Walrath page (below) works, but creates other issues associated with Citrix use

My question to you is if there is another potential solution or if there is a way to automatic the cycling of best performace/best appearance on boot.

Relevant websites in my search:

- https://aaronwalrath.wordpress.com/2010/12/05/fix-for-citrix-xenapp-published-apps-disabling-windows-visual-effects/
- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/952ef860-fe0b-469d-a51b-0fbf45cc3634/windows-10-animate-windows-when-minimizing-and-maximizing-not-working?forum=win10itprogeneral
- [Aero transitions not active at startup](https://superuser.com/questions/787905/aero-transitions-not-active-at-startup)

Comment: After wondering why a fresh Windows 11 install suddenly "broke", your question provided the answer. I am sad that this is still a problem today.

While not an answer, for now I have disabled automatic startup of the Citrix processes on my local machine, and that solves it. Animations will still turn off on the next connection, because clicking a Citrix remote link will launch CitrixWorkspace.

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, I applied the registry workaround in the answer from the last link (basically redirecting concentr.exe to a dummy executable permanently) and that works fine, visual effects are never disabled now. There doesn't seem to be any side effects in Citrix. I realize this likely breaks Connection Center but that's not how I connect to my remote system.