# Disable narrator-like "thing" in Office 2013

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2013, microsoft-word-2013, narrator

**tl;dr;** *Whenever when I press <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> in any Office 2013's product, a small narrator-like thing appears on screen. This is very annoying. How can I permanently disable this feature?*

---

A thing like this appears on screen I press <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> in any Office 2013's product:

[image]

What is this? How can I turn this thing off or force it not appear?

There's nothing under this *thing*'s settings button (speaker+gear icon). Read speed and voice type only. No way to disable this permanently, disable its keyboard shortcut etc.

I am more than certain that this is a purely Microsoft Office 2013+ feature:

- I managed to see it in Word 2013 and Outlook 2013 off-line version.
- It appears only on my two PCs having either Office 2013 or off-line versions of Office 365.
- It does not appear / exist in Office 2010.

Depending on scenario, situation or program that I am using in a particular moment:

- it just appears on the screen and annoys only,
- it starts reading following text aloud, moving cursor to next word, line or paragraph automatically.

I've read [this question and answers](https://superuser.com/q/473410/156554) as good as [this one](https://superuser.com/q/573728/156554). It is not a solution for me. And my question isn't a duplicate of those two mentioned. Mostly, because:

- **these two questions deals with *Narrator*, a Windows 10 feature, while the thing, I am asking about, is clearly Office feature,**
- I have disabled keyboard shortcut for Windows 10 Narrator in Narrator's settings,
- mentioned keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) does not activate anything on my PCs,
- I have only two voices (*Microsoft Adam* and *Microsoft Paulina*) in this little thing while I have five of them in total in *Narrator* settings.

**Is there any Office setting or any other solution to get rid of this permanently?**

My native language uses a bunch of characters that requires <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+*some letter* to be pressed in order to type them. I am typing texts at a quite high speed (300+ characters per second) and when I am typing texts in my native language, I am using <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+*some letter* shortcut many times per minute. If such character appears at beginning of a word and if I delay releasing space (entered before that word) just a few milliseconds, I have a nearly 100% chance that this little, annoying thing activates. It makes quick text editing really problematic and annoying.

Comment: When this small window pops up, have you used it to see which application it was related with?

Answer (score 1):

As correctly identified in the question, this is a feature that appears in Microsoft Outlook and Microsoft Word only and starting with version 2013.

Microsoft doesn't make their users' lives too easy. Not only, it introduces a feature that does exactly the same as system-wide Narrator, but also it makes disabling this quite difficult -- separate approaches are needed in both Outlook and Word. In Outlook this is a *regular feature* that can be disabled using corresponding configuration option. In Word this is a *hidden feature* that can be disabled by deleting its keyboard shortcut.

According to [this article](https://www.codetwo.com/blog/disabling-read-aloud-outlook-and-word/) to disable this Narrator-like feature **in Outlook**, go to *File > Options > Ease of Access* and clear the *Show Read Aloud* checkbox that appears in *Application display options*.

**in Word** you must:

1. Go to *File > Options > Customize Ribbon*.
2. Click *Customize...* button.
3. Select *Review Tab* item in *Categories* list and *ReadAloud* item in *Commands* list.
4. Select *Control+Alt+Space* item in *Current keys* list.
5. Click *Remove* button.

Once you close this window, you're done. More details and screenshots can be found [this article](https://www.codetwo.com/blog/disabling-read-aloud-outlook-and-word/).

Comment: Thank you!!! It was popping every time I typed "space" after typing the euro symbol, and it was really getting boring...