# How do I turn OFF Windows Narrator?

Tags: windows-8, ease-of-access

As a software developer I want to test my app under a variety of settings, so I played around with the Ease of Access settings on my Surface RT. Now I have the Narrator on and I cannot figure out how to turn it off again. It's making me crazy, because anything you tap on it just tells you what the control is, you have to double-tap to actually click it.

Please make my Surface usable for me again!

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/473410/disable-narrator-shortcut-key-in-windows-8

Answer (score 73, accepted):

> If you want to quickly exit Narrator, press <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Source: [Windows 8 Narrator page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/hear-text-read-aloud-with-narrator)

Comment: Ah, that's better! I found a long way around involving getting to the taskbar icon and tapping and double-tapping a lot. This way is much faster, thankyou.

Comment: This worked for me....^just as obliged as this guy...I must say I had to `refresh` my page for this to work.

Comment: By the way, it toggles on and off when you press Windows-Enter.

Answer (score 18):

Caps Lock + Esc didn't work for me, but Windows Logo + Enter did:

> Exiting Narrator
>
> There are also different ways to exit Narrator. These are the two
>   shortcuts many people prefer:
>
> On a keyboard, press the Windows logo key Windows logo key +Enter. On
>   a tablet, press the Windows logo button Windows logo key and Volume Up
>   button together.

Comment: please cite the source

Comment: I had use Windows Logo + Enter whilst the screen was locked, as for some reason this was the only time Narrator was speaking.

Comment: Windows-Enter is a toggle for it.  But to ensure it shuts up you can use Caps-Lock+Esc.

Comment: On my particular machine, running Windows 10 Enterprise N 2015 LTSB 10.0.10240, Caps+Esc stops the narrator, but Win+Enter only starts it.

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl + Alt + Delete, click Task Manager, Scroll down to background tasks, click Screen Reader, click End Task. This is the only thing that worked on my computer so I am posting this.

Answer (score 2):

As of Windows 10, you need to include the `Ctrl` key, which means that `Windows` + `Enter` is not enough: it needs to be `Windiws` + `Ctrl` + `Enter`.

Without the `Ctrl` key, you can also use `Narrator` + `Esc`, which depends on the configured `Narrator` key (Both the `Caps lock` and `Insert` keys serve as your `Narrator` key by default).

See [Appendix B: Narrator keyboard commands and touch gestures - Windows Help](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/22806/windows-10-narrator-keyboard-commands-touch-gestures) for a full table with commands and explanation about the `Narrator` key.

Note that

- [[WayBack](https://web.archive.org/web/20181215163210/https://twitter.com/jpluimers/status/1073978825447493632)] [currently](https://twitter.com/jpluimers/status/1073978825447493632) pages at support.microsoft.com cannot be saved in the [WayBack machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayback_Machine), so I have not included an archived link.
- `Caps Lock` + `Esc` does not work on an RDP connection originating from a Mac

Comment: But this question is tagged windows-8. I am not sure a Windows 10 answer is useful here. Has nobody asked about Narrator on Windows 10?

Comment: Nope. I got here searching how to exit Microsoft Narrator on Windows 10 via Google Search (:

Can it be solved by just adding a "Windows 10" tag? Or is that too much of a shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

A tip from the Microsoft [Accessibility on my phone](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/accessibility-on-my-phone) page:

*Turn on Narrator quick launch and you'll be able to turn Narrator on or off with a quick button combo—press and hold the Volume Up button button, and then press the Start button button.*

Comment: I was asking for the Surface RT tablet, not a phone

Answer (score 0):

Just could not make it die with the previous suggestions, so I did the following.

1. Windows-key + Q
2. Search for and run "narrator"
3. Open Task Manager (righ-click taskbar -> "Task Manager")
4. Go to details tab, find "Narrator.exe"
5. Right-click -> "End task"

Comment: That'll do it for sure.  But then you can't turn it back on as easily.

Answer (score 0):

IN Windows 8.1, go to the Settings, Ease of Use, Turn the Narrator off.

I'm not sure what turns it on, but this is the way to turn it off.

The sad part is that you have to know that it's called "Narrator" before you can figure out how to find setting adjustments for it.

Comment: Assuming you mean Ease of Access, this is covered by the answer from nc4pk.