# Windows 10, change hotkeys

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys

Is there any way to change the hotkeys in Windows 10? 
I've assigned super+return in Sublime Text but in Windows 10 this combination executes the narrator. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Also: [Disable Narrator shortcut key in windows 8](http://superuser.com/questions/473410/disable-narrator-shortcut-key-in-windows-8)

Answer (score -1):

[AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) can be used to create a wide variety of custom hotkeys and hotstrings in Windows.